# PHP - Name of first day in actual month

Tags: php

How can i get name (~Monday) of the first day in the current month? or just value (monaday=0, tuesday=1 ...)
in PHP?

I have $date = getdate(), i try make a calendar, but i need to know first day
offset in calendar.

EDIT:
fixed question: I'm asking of 1-st day only.

Comment: Do you mean the weekday (Wednesday) or the current month (March)?

Comment: You can use php date function for get name of day like echo date('l'); l (lowercase 'L')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you three letter starting day of current month

```
echo date('D',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1));
```

in numeric

```
echo date('N',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

See [**PHP: date**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for a list of formats you can use for working with dates. In your case you'll need the "l":

```
$day = date("l"); //$day will be the full name of the current day
```

**Update:**

To get the name of the first day of the current month, pass the current date as the second parameter:

```
$day = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), 1, date("Y")));
//date("m") is the numeric representation of the current month
//date("Y") is the four-digit representation of the current year
//$day will be the name of the day of the first of march of this year (thursday normally :D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Was interesting enough that I coded it for you. :-)

```
<?php
$month=date('m');
$year=date('Y');
$first=$month.'/1/'.$year;
$first=strtotime($first);
$weekday1=date('D',$first); //or $weekday1=date('l',$first);

echo $weekday1;
?>
```

in the comment, that 'l' is a lowercase "L".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you:

```
date('D', mktime(0,0,0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
echo date("l", mktime(0,0,0,date("M"), date("D"), date("Y));
```

or

```
echo date("w", mktime(0,0,0,date("M"), date("D"), date("Y));
```

l (lowercase 'L')   A full textual representation of the day of the week    Sunday through Saturday

w   Numeric representation of the day of the week   0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

Answer (score 0):

Use php date function for eg

```
 echo date("l"); //l (lowercase 'L')  It will return name of day 

   echo  date("N"); //ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
```