# How do you return an integer corresponding to the first day (Sunday, Monday...) of the month?

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
$day = date('w');
```

In PHP this returns a numeric representation of the current today so how do you return a numeric representation of the first day of the month?

Comment: like [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600335/php-name-of-first-day-in-actual-month) - `echo date('N',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Name of first day in actual month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600335/php-name-of-first-day-in-actual-month)

Answer (score 0):

First day of February 2019:

```
date('w', strtotime('2019-02'));
```

First day of current month:

```
date('w', strtotime(date('Y-m')));
```